# Svn/Apache user access "500 Internal Error" "Need AuthName" issue

Tags: svn, apache, authorization

Trying to setup SVN to use HTTP, with the user/auth user access files.

I have the following in the subversion.conf for the Apache Server:

```
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository/

       AuthzSVNAccessFile /asvn/svnAccessAuthz
       AuthType Basic
#      AuthName "Subversion Repository"
       AuthUserFile /asvn/svnUserAuthz
       Require valid-user
#
#   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
#   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
#      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
#      # SSLRequireSSL
#
#      AuthType Basic
#      AuthName "Authorization Realm"
#      AuthUserFile /path/to/passwdfile
#      Require valid-user
#   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I have the following in the user/password auth files (each file is set
to apache/apache/766 as a test)

```
/asvn/svnAccessAuthz
[/]
* = rw

[/repos]
* = rw

[/repos/trunk]
* = rw

[repos:/]
* = rw

[repos:/trunk]
* = rw

[/trunk]
* = rw



/asvn/svnUserAuthz
bill:$apr1$NsGWbE/9$695MXkrm8x06hMabC3Hu71

the svnUserAuthz file was create using:
 htpasswd -mb /etc/svnUserAuthz  bill qqqqqq
```

---

When I try to access the repos, using the following i get the Internal
500 error, with the "Need Authname /foo" in the apache err logs.

```
svn list --username bill --password qqqqqq http://192.168.1.45/repos
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error)
   in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://192.168.1.45/repos'
```

the error_log is:

```
 [Thu Mar 17 21:08:38 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.45] need AuthName: /repos/
 [Thu Mar 17 21:08:43 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.45] need AuthName: /repos/trunk
```

if I comment out the

```
#       AuthzSVNAccessFile /asvn/svnAccessAuthz
#       AuthType Basic
#       AuthName "Subversion Repository"
#       AuthUserFile /asvn/svnUserAuthz
#       Require valid-user
```

then I can easily access the repos, so I'm screwing up something with
the user/passwd access process.

i've set the access on the /asvn and the svn files to be:

```
 chmod 766
 chown apache.apache
```

so the files are completely accessible to the apache server...

I've tried numerous combinations in the auth file to try to get it to
allow access for a test user, but I'm completely stumped.

Thoughts/comments/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uff I have a bash script for this which I could sell :) 
It even creates my svn hooks :) 
I think you should not comment out the auth name

Here I give you some working configs from one of my svns.

```
<Location />
DAV svn
SVNPath '/var/svn/web1339/reproname'
SVNAutoversioning on
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'svn - reproname'
AuthUserFile '/var/svn/web1339/reproname/dav_svn.passwd'
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

the repro is owned by the apache user, it can be either apache or www-data depends on your system. apache on centos. www-data on debian.

With the tool htpasswd you can edit your password file.

```
                        htpasswd -bcs  "${reprofolder}/dav_svn.passwd" "$3" "$4"
```

$3 should be username $4 is the password.

Have fun and good luck.

Comment: hey guys.. and anyone else who runs into this issue when searching... the "AuthName" is apparently required!!!!! when it's not commented, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (from the snippets in your question) is `svnUserAuthz` file is present in `/etc` and not `/asvn` as expected by the apache configuration.